# What is a good Python module to access data in a MySQL/MariaDB database?

Tags: library, database, python, mysql, sql

I need to process a bunch of rows from a MySQL database table. I will be using Python as the programming language.

Requirements:

- Python module

  - reading the rows of an existing database/table
  - data is numeric, datetime, str, etc
  - reading the data returns Python objects/datatypes (i.e. int,float,str,etc,etc. not just a string or multiple strings.)
- supports MySQL
- RPM and/or DEB package available
- open-source
- the Python module must be actively developed[1]
- public code repo[2]

**Given these requirements, what is a good Python module to access data in MySQL/MariaDB database?**

Extra value go towards the following:

- a project that has positive growth[3]
- good example code, documentation, tutorials
- large user base
- supports MariaDB also (future work may transition from MySQL to MariaDB)

---

[1]
frequent commits (at least one commit per month, preferably one or more commits per week), at least 3 active developers

[2]
to allow me to pull down the code via some version control

[3]
users/developers/unittests/features/etc of the Python module are growing

Comment: I found two decent Python modules `MySQLdb` (sourceforge) and `sqlalchemy`. However I am not knowledgable about databases.

Comment: While I am with you that I prefer code that is still being maintained and aupported is better, but isn't that pretty fast? Or are commits different than conpile and publishing?

Comment: FYI from my brief google research looking into `MySQLdb` --> [`MySQLdb` appears to be abandoned as of 2014-01-02](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/39953/is-mysqldb-python-code-being-actively-developed-maintained)

Answer (score 1):

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) provides a d[atabase abstraction layer](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html?highlight=database#sql-queries) over SQLAlchemy with a fallback to sqlite.

- Read the rows of an existing DB - Definitely *but conceptually when using pandas dataframes you tend to think in columns* data can be read from tables or queries.
- Data is not text only - [Yes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html?highlight=database#sql-data-types): Pandas dataframes contain real, typed, data objects.
- Support MySQL - **[Yes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/index.html)** via SQLAlchemy
- Actively Developed - **Yes** for both Pandas and SQLAlchemy
- Public code repository: [Pandas is on GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas) while [SQLAchemy is on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/overview)

Activity as at 27 May 2017:

Pandas: From the GitHub [Pulse](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pulse): In the last month 169 pull requests by 54 Authors impacting 417 files.
SQLAchemy: BitBucket doesn't seem to have a pulse tool *that I can see* but looking at the logs suggests that it is less active but by no means dead with significant activity in the last few hours by multiple authors.